# IntelliJ - Spring Boot application suddenly will not compile

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, pentaho

I am developing an application using Spring Boot. It is fairly straightforward. It uses Quartz to schedule Pentaho jobs to import data into a Postgres database. It contains only 1 module(the original, no extras have been added. The project started out using Java 7 but within the first couple of weeks switched to Java 8. After the switch, everything ran fine(i.e the application would compile and launch). I started coding some new classes and when they were completed, I went to test them and the application wouldn't compile. I got an error stating that Java 8 was the wrong source code. I checked my project structure and both Global and Module compilers were set to Java 8. I did find that Gradle was still using Java 7. I changed Gradle to Java 8 and the error changed. The compile was still failing due to the following errors:

```
• error: package org.quartz does not exist import org.quartz.*;
• error: package org.quartz does not exist import org.quartz.*;
• error: package org.quartz does not exist import org.quartz.*;
• error: package org.quartz.impl does not exist import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
• error: package org.quartz.impl.matchers does not exist import org.quartz.impl.matchers.GroupMatcher;
• error: package org.pentaho.di.job does not exist import org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta;
• error: package org.pentaho.di.core.exception does not exist import org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException;
• error: package org.pentaho.di.core does not exist import org.pentaho.di.core.Result;
• error: package org.pentaho.di.core does not exist import org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment;
```

Quartz and Pentaho are not being found even though they are set up in the Project Structure:
[image]
I am fairly new to IntelliJ so any suggetions on what else to check or how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to reimport the dependencies. There should be an option somewhere in Gradle tool window.

Answer (score 1):

This can solve your problem. First ***clean*** your gradle project. After that you will need to ***refresh*** all your gradle deps by clicking on this blue arrows in gradle tool window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you found a solution, but I was experiencing a similar situation. I tried to remove current modules in the project settings, then added the project modules again. I then refreshed my Gradle and rebuilt my project.